# Failed to build native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3

I switched to Linux Mint About a Two weeks ago and want to install my bundle for my website but my terminal is giving me error
    Resolving dependencies.............
    Using rake 11.2.2
    Using i18n 0.7.0
    Using json 1.8.3
    Using minitest 5.9.0
    Using thread_safe 0.3.5
    Using builder 3.2.2
    Using erubis 2.7.0
    Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
    Using pkg-config 1.1.7
    Using rack 1.6.4
    Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
    Using arel 6.0.3
    Installing debug_inspector 0.0.2 with native extensions

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/ext    /debug_inspector
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20160830-6661-3kryhn.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/ext/debug_inspector
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/ext/debug_inspector
make "DESTDIR="
compiling debug_inspector.c
In file included from /usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:36:0,
             from debug_inspector.c:12:
/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/defines.h:26:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No     such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:239: recipe for target 'debug_inspector.o' failed
make: *** [debug_inspector.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0   /gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/debug_inspector-0.0.2/gem_make.out
Using bundler 1.11.2
Installing byebug 9.0.5 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/byebug-9.0.5/ext/byebug
```

/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20160830-6661-18ytmbw.rb extconf.rb
    creating Makefile

```
current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/byebug-9.0.5/ext/byebug
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/byebug-9.0.5/ext/byebug
make "DESTDIR="
compiling breakpoint.c
In file included from /usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:36:0,
             from /usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h:33,
             from byebug.h:4,
             from breakpoint.c:1:
/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/defines.h:26:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No   such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:239: recipe for target 'breakpoint.o' failed
make: *** [breakpoint.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/byebug-9.0.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/byebug-9.0.5/gem_make.out
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Using sass 3.4.22
Using tilt 2.0.5
Using spring 1.7.2
Installing sqlite3 1.3.11 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/ext/sqlite3
```

/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20160830-6661-3zztze.rb extconf.rb
    checking for sqlite3.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
    libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
    need configuration options.

```
Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.3
--with-sqlite3-dir
--without-sqlite3-dir
--with-sqlite3-include
--without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
--with-sqlite3-lib
--without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1144:in `block in find_header'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:942:in `block in checking_for'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block in postpone'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:941:in `checking_for'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1143:in `find_header'
from extconf.rb:30:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:
```

/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.11/mkmf.log
    extconf failed, exit code 1

```
Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.11/gem_make.out
Using turbolinks-source 5.0.0
Using rdoc 4.2.2
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Installing nokogiri 1.6.8 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri
```

/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20160830-6661-657qsw.rb extconf.rb
    Using pkg-config version 1.1.7
    checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
    libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
    need configuration options.

```
Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.3
--help
--clean
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to    generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `block in try_compile'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:522:in `with_werror'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `try_compile'
from extconf.rb:138:in `nokogiri_try_compile'
from extconf.rb:162:in `block in add_cflags'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:629:in `with_cflags'
from extconf.rb:161:in `add_cflags'
from extconf.rb:414:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:
```

/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.6.8/mkmf.log

```
extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.6.8/gem_make.out
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using mime-types 3.1
An error occurred while installing debug_inspector (0.0.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install debug_inspector -v '0.0.2'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

I tried to install the debug_inspector like this
    gem install debug_inspector -v 0.0.2
result:
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing debug_inspector:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/ext/     \debug_inspector
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20160830-6775-1iui5kl.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/ext  /debug_inspector
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/ext/debug_inspector
make "DESTDIR="
compiling debug_inspector.c
In file included from /usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:36:0,
             from debug_inspector.c:12:
/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/defines.h:26:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such   file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:239: recipe for target 'debug_inspector.o' failed
make: *** [debug_inspector.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/debug_inspector-0.0.2/gem_make.out
```

EDIT
json runs with the same error
will try to reinstall the whole ruby system
EDIT2
installing devkit and trying again

Comment: Not familiar with debug_inspector but I would bet that it is missing a native library. You need to find out what that library may be and install it.

Comment: is there a way i can reinstall all native libraries

Comment: i will try reinstalling all gems

Comment: it actually looks like devug_inspector depends on nokogiri (XML library) - try to reinstall nokogiri and check what errors you get then. (nowadays nokogiri comes with its own native library so it normally "just works" but it has been the source of many similar problems in the past!)

Comment: failed to install nokogiri same problem if i may point out a problem thats been worrying me the with nokogiri is the    You have to install development tools first    could that be the problem

Comment: Aha are you using the system ruby?

Comment: Here is a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33968122/nokogiri-issues-with-ruby-on-rails/33978559

Comment: If you are telling nokogiri to use system libraries you'll need these installed: libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libiconv-dev

Comment: debug_inspector installed but nokogiri and one gem failed same problem

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Following Code Fixed my Problem

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential patch

sudo apt-get install ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

For Rails on Linux Mint 18, add libraries:

```
build-essential patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev libsqlite3-dev
```

Comment: i didnt need libsqlite3-dev

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
```

Which I found after lot of research on this [link](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/51452).